# pushpins with description in url

Tags: html, iframe, bing-maps, pushpin, infobox

I am struggling a bit with this piece of code :

="http://www.bing.com/maps/embed/viewer.aspx?v=3&cp="&Latitude&"~"&Longitude&"&lvl=17&w=300&h=200&sty=r&typ=s&pp=~~"&Latitude&"~"&Longitude&"&ps=55&dir=0&mkt=en-gb&src=SHELL&form=BMEMJS'>"

I created in Sharepoint 2010 a calculated column and it allow me to retrieve fields from my list and to generate a pushpin on the embeded map,

The only problem I got is that I try (from the field Identified as [Building Name]) to obtain an infobox on the pushpin.

Any idea how to place that in the URL ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding the Bing Maps consumer site inside of internal applications like this is against the terms of use of Bing Maps. If you want to use Bing Maps inside of SharePoint you have to use the full development API or one of the existing webparts.

Comment: Good evening Ricky, Could you explain me what would be the best line of action in this particular case ? I already have a BingMap Key but I tried the previous code due to the fact that I cannot link the SP2010 list to a HTML code Content editor ( Sadly the only code I have found on the web require SharePoint Designer 2010 or are Google Map Based )>

Comment: I wrote a blog post on how to connect a SharePoint list of Bing maps a while ago. You can find it here: http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/03/26/connecting-a-sharepoint-list-to-bing-maps.aspx

Comment: Ricky, at the end we have manage with the GIS Team to incorporate our GIS Solution already based on BingMap (MapThat from Cadline) on SharePoint and the mapping system just read from a SP2010 list the coordinates. Once again thank you very much for your help and your time.